# How to add fade in/out effect to pjax-standalone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, pjax

I'm using [PJAX-Standalone](https://github.com/thybag/PJAX-Standalone) to load pages for a website, and I'd like to add fade out/in transitions when new content is loaded, however, I'm not sure how best to achieve this.

The PJAX documentation describes 'callbacks', is there a way to append a fade transition to one of these, so that existing content fades out while new content fades in? I'm jumping into this head first as a jQuery/Javascript noob, but I'm eager to learn, so any help/advice is much appreciated!

This is what I have included in my wrapper.php:

```js
// PJAX links!
  pjax.connect({
    'container': 'content',
    'success': function(event){
      var url = (typeof event.data !== 'undefined') ? event.data.url : '';
      console.log("Successfully loaded "+ url);
    },
    'error': function(event){
      var url = (typeof event.data !== 'undefined') ? event.data.url : '';
      console.log("Could not load "+ url);
    },
    'ready': function(){
    console.log("PJAX loaded!");
    }
  });
```

Comment: please include your code so far into the question

Comment: Will do, one sec...

Comment: you may use jquery ?

Comment: The site I built is more or less a heavily modified version of the 'test' example on the PJAX page, so the overall structure (index.php that calls wrapper.php on load) is the same

Comment: I only asked do you use jquery on site, not the page hierarchy :)

Comment: Yes, ready to use jQuery.

Comment: Please describe what does this pjax do ( how it does it) in edit of your question, because I'm not an expert in it, probably it can be done by jquery only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to go about this is to just hide the container that wraps the `#content` div and then fade it in after the content is loaded.  It will be a little harder to fade the content out and then fade the new content in and really you don't gain much by fading it out and the pjax container will load the content faster than you can fade it out so it will look silly to fade it out.  Since you said in the comments below the question that you can use jquery I will just use that because it the easiest.  So what I would do is wrap your content that you want to fade in with a container and give it an id of `#content-container`.  If you are using a markup similar to the markup on the github page you can use something like the following:

```
<div id='content-container>
    <div class='container'>
        <div id='content' class='col-sm-8'>
            <?php echo $contents; ?>            
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>
            ... sidebar stuff ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        ... footer stuff ...
    </footer>
</div>
```

And your javascript and jquery code will look like:

```
    // PJAX links!
    pjax.connect({
        'container': 'content',
        'success': function(event){
            var url = (typeof event.data !== 'undefined') ? event.data.url : '';
            console.log("Successfully loaded "+ url);
        },
        'error': function(event){
            var url = (typeof event.data !== 'undefined') ? event.data.url : '';
            console.log("Could not load "+ url);
        },
        'ready': function(){
            console.log("PJAX loaded!");
        },
        'beforeSend': function(e){
            $('#content-container').hide();
        },
        'complete': function(e){
            $('#content-container').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
```

So what is happening is we are hiding the `#content-container` on pjax `beforeSend` then fading it back in on pjax `complete` like it says in the callbacks section of the documentation.  You can control the speed at which it fades in by changing the number where it says `.fadeIn(1000)`  changing it to say 800 will make it faster.

Anyway hope this wasn't too confusing if you have any questions hit me up in the comments below.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the in-depth explanation! Everything is working perfectly!